# Jquery - Filtering a-z from xml file is showing only the last result in the xml file

Tags: jquery

I've got a little document library and I'm having trouble getting the below code to display the results correctly (in the process of learning jquery).  It reads the file fine tells me there are 3 results if for example I click on B but only displays the last result.  The page below gets called into another page where the jquery_version_using sits. It's been driving myself and a colleague up the wall so I've turned to the wider community to see if you peeps have any ideas.  The xml file it's self is nothing special.  Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tablesorter.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">          

        $('button').click(function() {
        // alert($(this).val());
        var azRef = $(this).val();
            $.ajax ({
                type: "GET",
                url: "data/alldata.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                cache: false,
                success: function(response) {

                $('#result').html('');  

                var row;
                var i = 0;

                $(response).find('indices').children().each(function() {

                var azIndex = '';
                var exp = '';
                var searchAZ = '';
                var pub = '';

                var azdoc = $(this);
                var title = azdoc.find('title').text();     
                var ref = $(this).find('reference').attr("ref");
                var ref_link = $(this).find('reference').attr("ref_link");
                var docLink = '<a href="' + ref_link + '" > ' + ref + ' </a>';              
                var type = azdoc.find('type').text();
                var status = azdoc.find('status').text();
                azIndex = azdoc.find('azindex').text();

                exp = new RegExp(azRef,"gi");

                searchAZ = azIndex.match(exp);

                if  (searchAZ != null) {

                if ((i % 2) == 0) { row = 'even'; }
                else { row = 'odd'; }               

                i++;                

                pub += '<tr class="row ' + row + '">' + '\n';
                pub += '<td valign="top" class="col1">' + title + '</td>' + '\n';
                pub += '<td valign="top" class="col2">' + docLink + '</td>' + '\n';
                pub += '<td valign="top" class="col3">' + status + '</td>' + '\n';              
                pub += '</tr>' + '\n';

                showResult ( pub );

                 }      

                function showResult (resultSet) {


                pub = '<div class="message">There are ' + i + ' results!</div>';
                pub += '<table id="grid" border="0">' + '\n';
                pub += '<thead><tr>' + '\n';
                pub += '<th class="col1">Title</th>' + '\n';
                pub += '<th class="col2">Link</th>' + '\n';
                pub += '<th class="col3">Status</th>' + '\n';
                pub += '</tr></thead>' + '\n';
                pub += '<tbody>' + '\n';                

                pub += resultSet;

                pub += '</tbody>' + '\n';
                pub += '</table>' + '\n';

                $('#result').html(pub);

                $('#grid').tablesorter(); 

                }


});
}
});
});


</script>

<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td><button value="9" >0-9</button> |</td>
        <td><button value="A" >A </button> |</td>
        <td><button value="B" >B </button> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">C</a> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">D</a> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">E</a> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">F</a> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">G</a> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">H</a> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">I</a> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">J</a> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">K</a> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">L</a> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">M</a> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">N</a> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">O</a> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">P</a> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">Q</a> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">R</a> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">S</a> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">T</a> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">U</a> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">V</a> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">W</a> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">X</a> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">Y</a> |</td>
        <td><a href="#">Z</a></td>      
    </tr>
</table>
<hr>

<div id="result">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: why do you declare the function showResult inside the ajax success block?

Comment: Example I was using to help create this had it in :) - I'm a bit of a n00b with jquery

Answer (score 0):

In `showResults()` you call this:

```
$('#result').html(pub);
```

Every time `showResults()` get's called, the contents of `#result` is overwritten. That's the reason you only see the last item.

You could try `append()` instead:

```
$('#result').append(pub);
```

Comment: Tried with $('#result').html(pub); and with out it made no difference and if I use append it give me the you have 1 result followed by title lines then the result..then you have 2 results etc for the next then 3 results for the 3rd and so forth. I'm not sure if something to do with the part generating the rows as the end part, creating the table, seems fine.

Comment: what does that `tableSorter` do?

Comment: It's a nice little plugin from http://tablesorter.com/docs/ allows you to sort the table, did try running the code with out it but same result with out the formatting

Comment: Well I can't see the problem like this. Maybe you should just debug it a little bit, try `console.log(response)` inside the ajax success function

Comment: Ok, try this: `$('#result').append(pub.clone());`